# saving SQL server date with respect to time zones

Tags: sql-server, date

I read the date documentation for SQL server and I just want to be sure that I m doing the right thing here,

I m trying to save the date and time of creating the record using `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` but I understand that this value does not correspond to the client date and time, if the client in a different time zone. so my thinking is,
saving using `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` and save the time zone of the client and then later I can display the time in the client corresponding date and time, is there another way of doing it?

What is the best way of saving date/time for displaying it later to the client in correspondence to their time zone?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Save everything as UTC and convert to user's time zone as late as possible in the call stack (ie. ideally in the presentation layer).

Comment: @Igor said exactly the same thing I would suggest.

Comment: Can you please put it as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save everything as UTC and convert to user's time zone as late as possible in the call stack (ie. ideally in the presentation layer).

Comment: Do you suggest using `datetimeoffset`?  Or just `datetime2` with a business rule that the application always saves a UTC datetime?

Comment: @BaconBits - The latter is my personal preference with the assumption that all dates in the DB are always stored as UTC.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to save time is to save in UTC . Refer [SYSUTCDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql) . It will be easily be converted to different time zones based on need. If you have client timezone, you can convert the time to corresponding client time zone. Refer [SwitchOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/switchoffset-transact-sql).